# Возможно ли программно отключить GPS если объект выехал за город?

Tags: java, android, gps

Программа клиент для рекламной компании. Человек клеит себе наклейку на стекло и катается с ней по городу рекламируя что либо. Есть условие: рекламодатель платит только за рекламацию внутри города. Так вот, можно ли реализовать проверку на андроиде, человек находится внутри города или нет?

Километраж должен считаться только если объект двигается внутри города. Мне надо знать, сколько км он проехал по городу. И не отключать сам GPS, а сделать проверку, если объект выехал за город - километраж ему не считать, пока он в него не вернётся....

Как реализовать такую проверку программно?

Comment: Имхо это маразм. Отключить то можно, а как же обратно его включить, когда объект обратно въедет в город - GPS то отключен, соответственно вы никогда не узнаете въехал он обратно в город или нет :) Подумайте сначала о логике.

Comment: @Barmaley согласен, возможно автору стоит не отключать GPS, а лишь увеличивать интервал между отправкой данных

Answer (score 3):

я боюсь, что Вам придется очерчивать каждый город, где это работает вручную на карте, используя многоугольники. Если многоугольник получился не выпуклым, то разбивать на несколько выпуклых и проверять попадает ли координата GPS в Ваш многоугольник, используя один из методов из [этой статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83)